# JavaScript addEventListener & initializing function conflicting, trying to update global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm developing a game interaction menu, and it is a HTML menu that will show actions depending on what job the player is having at the moment.

My issue: I retrieve information about the players job via window.addEventListener. It's being sent from my game Lua file to JavaScript. I can confirm that this is working. However, on the JavaScript part there are problems.

The job is being stored/retrieved/updated in the addEventListener under item.updateJob, as a variable named playerJob. This will also update the global variable with the same name. As you can see in the code, the init() function is being run before the window.addEventListener. init() has to use the updated global variable playerJob to show the correct menu, but it does not. When debugging it in the console it tells me it is "undefined". I have tried to put the window.addEventListener above the init() function inside §( function ... code, but that didn't do anything.

How can I make sure that the window.addEventListener is being run and set the playerJob variable before init() function does anything at all? I tried placing a global variable on top and did this: playerJob = "police", then it worked fine. Anyone knows how I can do this?

```
    var playerJob;

    $( function() {
        // Adds all of the correct button actions 
            console.log("Before int: ", playerJob)
            init();

        // Gets the interactionmenu div container 
        var interactionContainer = $( "#interactionmenu" );

        // Listens for NUI messages from Lua 
        window.addEventListener( 'message', function( event ) {
            var item = event.data;


            // Show the menu 
            if ( item.showmenu ) {
                ResetMenu()
                interactionContainer.show();
            }

            if ( item.hidemenu ) {
                interactionContainer.hide(); 
            }

            // This will update the players job, and does work!
            if ( item.updateJob ) {
                playerJob = item.job; 
                setJob(playerJob);
                console.log("playerJob set to: ", playerJob)
            }                   
        } );
    } )

    // Hides all div elements that contain a data-parent, in
    // other words, hide all buttons in submenus. 
    function ResetMenu() {
        $( "div" ).each( function( i, obj ) {
            var element = $( this );

            if ( element.attr( "data-parent" ) ) {
                element.hide();
            } else {
                element.show();
            }
        } );
    }

    // Configures every button click to use its data-action, or data-sub
    // to open a submenu. 
    function init() {
        // Loops through every button that has the class of "menuoption"
        $( ".menuoption" ).each( function( i, obj ) {

            // If the button has a data-action, then we set it up so when it is 
            // pressed, we send the data to the lua side. 
            if ( $( this ).attr( "data-action" ) ) {
                $( this ).click( function() { 
                    var data = $( this ).data( "action" ); 

                    sendData( "ButtonClick", data ); 
                } )
            }

            // If the button has a data-sub, then we set it up so when it is 
            // pressed, we show the submenu buttons, and hide all of the others.
            if ( $( this ).attr( "data-sub" ) ) {
                $( this ).click( function() {
                    var menu = $( this ).data( "sub" );
                    var element = $( "#" + menu ); 
                    element.show();
                    $( this ).parent().hide();  
                } )
            }

            // Here I'd like to know the playerJob, and want via item.updateJob in the addEventListener
            // However it returns undefined, no matter if I place the init() above or below
            // My question is: how can I make sure the item.updatePlayer job in the addEventListener updates
            // the variable globally and makes sure that it does that before this function is being run? 
            console.log("right before data-require: ", playerJob)   // returns undefined X amount of times.         

            if ( ( $( this ).attr ( "data-require" ) == "police" && playerJob != "police") ) {
                $( this ).hide();
            }

            else if ( ( $( this ).attr ( "data-require" ) == "mecano" && playerJob != "mecano") ) {
                $( this ).hide();
            }

            else if ( ( $( this ).attr ( "data-require" ) == "ambulance" && playerJob != "ambulance") ) {
                $( this ).hide();
            }
        } );

    }

    // Send data to lua for processing.
    function sendData( name, data ) {
        $.post( "http://wk_interactionmenu/" + name, JSON.stringify( data ), function( datab ) {
            if ( datab != "ok" ) {
                console.log( datab );
            }            
        } );
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question properly, you want `init` only to be run once you've received the `message` event, and therefore `playerJob` has been set.

I think what you're not understanding is that the `addEventListener` call isn't running the listener, it's just setting it up. The issue is that that `message` event isn't coming through until later. That's why you're getting `undefined` when you look at `playerJob`.

But you don't want `init` to be run more than once, and so didn't want it to be run from the event handler.

You could set a flag `var didInit = false;` instead of your current call to `init()`, in the same spot. Then, in your event handler, after you set `playerJob`, check the status of `didInit`. If it's not yet true, set it to true and run your `init` function.

Here's a replacement for your onLoad (`$(function(){...`) function which should do the job:

```
$( function() {
    // Did we initialize yet?
    var didInit = false;

    // Gets the interactionmenu div container
    var interactionContainer = $( "#interactionmenu" );

    // Listens for NUI messages from Lua 
    window.addEventListener( 'message', function( event ) {
        var item = event.data;


        // Show the menu
        if ( item.showmenu ) {
            ResetMenu()
            interactionContainer.show();
        }

        if ( item.hidemenu ) {
            interactionContainer.hide();
        }

        // This will update the players job, and does work!
        if ( item.updateJob ) {
            playerJob = item.job;
            setJob(playerJob);
            console.log("playerJob set to: ", playerJob)

            // Initialize if we didn't yet
            if (!didInit) {
                didInit = true;
                init();
            }
        }
    } );
} )
```

Does the player's job ever change? If so, you'd presumably want to run the part of the init code which hides buttons again, and you'd want to change it to show any now-relevant buttons which were previously hidden.

If that's the case, it might be worth splitting `init` into two parts -- one which you can run at the very beginning (as your original code does) which doesn't rely on `playerJob`, and another which can be run any time `playerJob` changes (including the first time it's set) and updates the UI. You could then run this (without any conditional or `didInit` flag) as part of your event handler.

Comment: The init() function runs to prepare some buttons for a menu, and it has to be run first in order to hide some buttons that the player doesn't have access to unless the player got the correct job. That's why I find it complicated to detect the player's job at the same time as I am running the init() function.

Once I press the hotkey button in-game, it runs the init function to prepare the buttons - then display it. The data-require hides all buttons the player doesn't have access to, but if the player got e.g a "police" job, he should have access to the data-require = "police".

Comment: I just edited my answer with some more advice regarding if playerJob ever changes -- some of it is relevant to your comment here. The thing is, you can't know the job until the event comes through, and so how could you know which buttons to hide? So if you don't want to show any of the existing UI yet until you know, you need a new piece of UI. Maybe greyed-out/disabled buttons, or a loading screen?

Comment: It's a "sub-script" and as soon as the player loads in it'll send the message instantly to addEventListener. Tried the code, didn't work - just displayed all the buttons, including those who are not supposed to be shown.

Comment: You're still not understanding that the event doesn't come through immediately. You say it comes "instantly", but it is asynchronous with respect to your code. You say it's not working, but I can't see why it wouldn't. Add a log message to the beginning of the `init` function. You should then see `playerJob set to: police`, followed by `init running`. What do you see?

Comment: I tried again and now it works. Thank you so much, been struggeling so much with it. Not familiar with flags and events, thank you!! <3

Comment: Great. Do consider breaking that function up into stuff you want to run immediately on load (but which doesn't need to know the job), and stuff which should run after the job is set or changes.

Comment: Did that now, thanks. Moved all data-requires in a function that I named init1() and the rest left in init which will start at first. However, now I'd like to update/refresh the init1 whenever I send a addEventListenerMessage.

So in your if(!didInit) { 
    didInit = true;
   init1();
}
I added didinit = false; below, so whenever I call it again it'll do the init1() once more. That didn't work, it hides the button but doesn't display the new one (e.g if I change to another job). Any suggestions? :D

Comment: It sounds like you just don't need the flag any more. But I don't think I can really help without seeing the current code, preferably somewhere I can run and tweak it like in a jsfiddle.

Comment: It's made for a game so most of the functions or what's releated to the JavaScript files requires the game file to be triggered. But I have uploaded the .js file to pastebin if that helps. https://pastebin.com/Wk6s32Gn

Comment: Your `init1` function only ever hides things, never shows them. Do you maybe just need to run `ResetMenu` again before `init1`? Or modify it so it shows as well as hides, as appropriate.

Comment: I tried using the ResetMenu(), however it only displayed the menu and didn't do anything special, couldn't even close the menu afterwards. Also tried making a variable to use .show instead of .hide if it was already run once, but that didn't do much. Hmm weird. There's no "reload/refresh" function to refresh the whole menu?

Comment: Not until you write one. It's seeming increasingly like this is someone else's code. Work at understanding each part of it before trying to modify it. But anyway, you could try replacing the loop with just this, which should hopefully do what you want: `$('.menuoption').each(function() { $(this).toggle($(this).data('require') === playerJob); });`

Comment: Yes the code is just modified by me, and is orginally released for the game that I'm using it for. I'll give it a try, thanks!

Comment: Actually I've tried using that toggle function before (tried again), but that ONLY displays the "playerjob" menu, not the rest of the menu, unfortunately.

Comment: `actionContainer.show();`, like you have elsewhere in your code? I'm bowing out. You're not giving enough information, and not showing that you've actually tried on your own.

Comment: Understandable, but it is in fact .hide I use elsewhere in my code where data-require is a part of the code.